# Vertex on character have frozen

Tags: modeling

I make copies of my projects as I progress, to keep things safe in case a job gets destroyed. I came into this project I'm working on and all the vertices on the characters body are frozen, I can't move them at all. It is only the body, everything else I can edit, as you can see I have moved a vertices on the characters tunic. Everything[image] is up to date, Blender 3.4.1, OS updated, drivers updated. I had this happen  about a year ago and ended up going back three revisions and building back, a real time consumer. The selection operator is enabled in the outliner, it just will not let me move any vertices on the character itself.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file?

Comment: Thanks but, I figured it out. I opened both the older version on one screen and the frozen one on the other and went parameter by parameter through the menus and settings and saw where the vertex edit mode was enabled in Vertex Groups. Turning that off fixed the "problem".

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Under the Vertex tab in Shape Keys, I had left the edit vertex button on, that froze all the vertices on the body. Turned it off and everything freed up.[image]

Comment: wow what a hard to find one   :p

Comment: Yah, but I get very stubborn sometimes and refused to quit digging for the reason I make dumb mistakes...and fix them. "I'll find the thing if it kills me"